# Convert string to HH:MM time in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am new to Python so apologies if this is a simple fix.

I currently have a column of times that are currently stored as strings and look as below when I view my dataframe:

```
bus_no   time
Bus1     2.0
Bus2     840.0
Bus3     2340.0
Bus4     15.0
Bus5     1205.0
Bus6     1304.0
Bus7     1620.0
Bus8     9.0
```

So 9.0 equates to 00:09, 1620 to 16:20. (It is a rather large dataset with many more fields so I created that example to easily show the format it is showing)

Each time I have tried to convert it to time it also forms a date and merges part of the time into the date thus producing an inaccurate output. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html)s:

```
#remove NaNs rows in time column if necessary
#df = df.dropna(subset=['time'])
#or replace NaNs to 0
#df['time1'] = df['time1'].fillna(0)

#convert to int, then str and add 0 
s = df['time'].astype(int).astype(str).str.zfill(4)
#add : twice
df['time1'] = s.str[:2] + ':' + s.str[2:] + ':00'
#convert to timedeltas
df['time2'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['time1'])
print (df)
  bus_no    time     time1    time2
0   Bus1     2.0  00:02:00 00:02:00
1   Bus2   840.0  08:40:00 08:40:00
2   Bus3  2340.0  23:40:00 23:40:00
3   Bus4    15.0  00:15:00 00:15:00
4   Bus5  1205.0  12:05:00 12:05:00
5   Bus6  1304.0  13:04:00 13:04:00
6   Bus7  1620.0  16:20:00 16:20:00
7   Bus8     9.0  00:09:00 00:09:00
```

Answer (score 0):

First, to make your string more consistent, you can use `str.zfill(x)` to make them of the same length. For example:

```
"9.0".zfill(6)
```

will give you "0009.0". Then, you can do something like

```
df.time.apply(lambda x: x[0:2] + ":" + x[2:4])
```

to convert it to "HH:MM" format.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
def get_time(s):
    s = s.replace('.0','')
    time_type = len(s)
    if len(s) == 1:
        return '00:0%s'%s
    elif len(s) == 2:
        return '00:%s'%s
    elif len(s) == 3:
        return '0%s:%s'%(s[0:1], s[1:3])
    elif len(s) == 4:
        return '%s:%s'%(s[0:2], s[2:4])
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you are after and the format of the data in the `time` column.

From the sample you give, it seems like your `time` column only includes `float`. But let's assume that it could as well include `int` and `str` formatted data.

Let's also assume that your dataframe is defined as following

```
>>>df.head()

    time
0      2
1 1620.0
2    155
3    120
4  123.0
```

Then you could first convert the `time` column to string with the following command

```
df.time = df.time.astype(str).astype(float).astype(int).astype(str)
```

Which now includes the time as string formatted `int`. Then you can add leading zeros by

```
df.time = df.time.str.zfill(4)

>>>df.head()

    time
0   0002
1   1620
2   0155
3   0120
4   0123
```

Then you can either use `apply` to map the `time_string` column like this

```
df['time_string'] = df.time.apply(lambda x: x[0:2] + ":" + x[2:4])
```

Or convert it first to `datetime` and then extract the date string from that object. This might be an unnecessary step for you though - but I like to work time objects as `datetime` in Python

```
df['time_datetime'] = df.time.apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x,'%H%M'))
df['time_string'] = df.time_datetime.apply(lambda x: x.strftime("%H:%M"))

>>>df.head()

   time       time_datetime             time_string
0  0002       1900-01-01 00:02:00       00:02
1  1620       1900-01-01 16:20:00       16:20
2  0155       1900-01-01 01:55:00       01:55
3  0120       1900-01-01 01:20:00       01:20
4  0123       1900-01-01 01:23:00       01:23
```

Answer (score 0):

Thouse who want to convert '1:27 PM' to 24 hour format

```
from datetime import datetime
def twelve_to_twentyfour(t):
"""
input: t '1:27 PM'
output '13:27'
"""
in_time = datetime.strptime(t, "%I:%M %p")
out_time = datetime.strftime(in_time, "%H:%M")
return out_time

df['time'].apply(lambda x: twelve_to_twentyfour(x))
```